# How to draw a circle in Drawable.draw

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, drawable

Q1. The `R.drawable.wallpaper` can show but the point cannot show.

Q2. Moreover, how to put an other image in

`Drawable bitmap = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wallpaper);`

I mean 2 pictures mix.

```
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

    Drawable bitmap = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wallpaper);
    bitmap.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getIntrinsicWidth(), bitmap.getIntrinsicHeight());

    Bitmap point = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            bitmap.getIntrinsicWidth(), 
            bitmap.getIntrinsicHeight(), 
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
                );

    Paint radius = new Paint(); radius.setColor(Color.RED);
    radius.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL); radius.setStrokeWidth(1);
    radius.setAntiAlias(true);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(point);
    canvas.drawCircle((float)(5), (float)(5), 5, radius);

    bitmap.draw(canvas);

    img.setImageDrawable(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the Android SDK samples. There are several examples in the ApiDemos project:

/ApiDemos/res/drawable/

black_box.xml
shape_5.xml
etc
It will look something like this for a circle with a gradient fill: